# Publicar proyecto WPF con base de datos en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, wpf

Buenas, tengo un proyecto que hice en visual studio (WPF) y que ya esta "terminado", este proyecto lo conecte a una base de datos que hice con SQL Server Management, mi pregunta es como puedo "publicar" o crear un archivo .exe de esta aplicación para poder instalarla en otro pc y como puedo "trasladar" la base de datos a ese otro pc para que pueda funcionar correctamente, desta ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede crear el Proyecto de Configuración en el **menu**

Archivo-> Nuevo -> Proyecto -> Otro Tipo de Proyecto -> Configuración e Implementación -> Instalador de Visual Studio -> Proyecto de Configuración.

Entonces, en Solution Explorer, puede agregar un proyecto existente. Después de agregar su proyecto, puede agregar la salida de su programa en la ventana Sistema de archivos le das clic con el botón derecho en Carpeta de la aplicación -> Agregar -> Salida del proyecto..., de modo que seleccione su proyecto de Proyecto ComboBox.

Después de agregar la salida de su proyecto, puede construir su proyecto de configuración y tendrá su archivo de configuración en su proyecto de configuración. Para más información puedes consultar:

[Pasos para crear la configuración y la implementación](http://www.fordevs.com/2009/07/steps-to-create-setup-and-deployment-project-in-dot-net-vs-2008.html)

[Instalación](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8f7a3d05-a2df-41ac-bacd-e4ab4a289578/how-to-create-setup-file-for-my-c-windows-applications?forum=vssetup)